# Can I use the Android Maps API with my own images?

Tags: android, image, maps

The app i want to build simply navigates an image of a building plan, along with a textview and a button.  I want to be able to do the following:

- Zoom in to a certain location of the image programmatically
- When zoomed in/out, the button and the textview shouldn't be scaled along with the image, exactly like the Maps API
- A line should be drawn to show the path between two rooms (not important for now)

Can I use the Maps API to manipulate an image?
If not, what should I use instead?

Thanks

Comment: Do you actually need the advanced mapping features provided by Maps, or is your primary goal more focused on displaying an image and zooming in and out on that image?

Comment: My app is focused on displaying an image and zooming in/out to a certain location on the image, x, y coordinates

Comment: for example in the image there is and office, i want to zoom in to that office and then move the picture programmaticly to another office (x, y coordinates) while showing the path between the two offices

Answer (score 0):

> can I use Maps API for an image?

Yes my friend you can. They are called GroundOverlays on the GoogleMaps API.

Once you have your map running you can add a GroundOverlay this way:

```
LatLng NEWARK = new LatLng(40.714086, -74.228697);

GroundOverlayOptions newarkMap = new GroundOverlayOptions()                  //Helper object to build the overlay
    .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.newark_nj_1922))  //Choose the image you want to use for the overlay
    .position(NEWARK, 8600f, 6500f);                                         //set the position for the center if the image and the height and width of the image
map.addGroundOverlay(newarkMap);                                             //Now just add it to your map and that's it! the system will handle the rest.
```

> I want to be able to do the following: -Zoom in to a certain location of the image Programmatically

Zoom in or out programmatically is fairly easy too:

```
//Pass the location where you wanna center the zoom and a float indicating the level of zoom you want
CameraUpdateFactory update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(18.902072, -98.980203), 17);
map.moveCamera(update);
```

And just to make sure [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/)you can find all the necessary to set up you map and more information about Overlays